# How to create a @Transaction in Spring to control rollback with two different databases?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have two different databases oracle.

I have implemented the confuration to work with two databases Using SpringBoot:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "br.com.xyz.univers.ms.universcontractsync.repository.universcontract",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "universContractEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "universContractTransactionManager"
)
public class UniversContractDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.universcontract")
    public DataSourceProperties universContractDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.universcontract.hikari")
    public DataSource universContractDataSource() {
        return universContractDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "universContractEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean universContractEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(universContractDataSource())
                .packages("br.com.xyz.univers.ms.universcontractsync.models.universcontract")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "universContractTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager universContractTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("universContractEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean universContractEntityManagerFactory) {
        if (universContractEntityManagerFactory == null) {
            throw new SyncUnknowException("universContractEntityManagerFactory is null");
        }
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = universContractEntityManagerFactory.getObject();
        if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
            throw new SyncUnknowException("entityManagerFactory is null");
        }
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

**The problem is how can i control the transaction when a method call the two databases? It's necessary because my method needs to all the both databases.**

Example the method:

```
@Override
@Transactional("chainedTransactionManager")
public void save(CompanyDTO companyDTO) {
    log.info("method=save  ' - CompanyServiceImpl");
    CompanyDTO companyDTOWithLegacyCode = companyDTO.toBuilder().build();
    legacyCodeService.changeToLegacyCode(companyDTOWithLegacyCode);
    Company company = companyBuilder.universContractDtoToSisbfEntity(companyDTOWithLegacyCode);
    companyRepository.save(company);
    legacyCodeService.updateLegacyCode(ClassTypeEnum.COMPANY, companyDTO.getCompanyCode(), company.getCompanyCode());
    log.info("finish method=save  ' - CompanyServiceImpl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Transactional annotation for both databases by specifying its value explicitly. Example @Transactional(value="chainedTransactionManager"). So that spring takes care of that.